# How to get the document with max value for a field with map-reduce in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, field, max, pymongo

How do I find the document with the maximum `uid` field with map-reduce in pymongo?

I have tried the following but it prints out blanks:

```
from pymongo import Connection
from bson.code import Code

db = Connection().map_reduce_example
db.things.insert({  
    "_id" : "50f5fe8916174763f6217994", 
    "deu" : "Wie Sie sicher aus der Presse und dem Fernsehen wissen, gab es in Sri  Lanka mehrere Bombenexplosionen mit zahlreichen Toten.\n", 
    "uid" : 13, 
    "eng" : "You will be aware from the press and television that there have been a  number of bomb explosions and killings in Sri Lanka." 
})

db.things.insert({  
    "_id" : "50f5fe8916234y0w3fvhv234", 
    "deu" : "Ich bin schwanger foo bar.\n", 
    "uid" : 14, 
    "eng" : "I am pregnant foobar." 
})

db.things.insert({  
    "_id" : "50f5fe8916234y0w3fvhv234", 
    "deu" : "barbar schwarz sheep, haben sie any foo\n", 
    "uid" : 14, 
    "eng" : "barbar black sheep, have you any foo" 
})

m = Code("function () {emit(this.uid,{'uid':this.uid,'eng':this.eng})}")

r = Code("function (key, values) {var total = 0;for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {total += values[i];}return total;}")


result = db.things.inline_map_reduce(m, r)

for r in result:
    print
```

An example document that look like these:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("50f5fe8916174763f6217994"), 
    "deu" : "Wie Sie sicher aus der Presse und dem Fernsehen wissen, gab es mehrere Bombenexplosionen mit zahlreichen Toten.\n", 
    "uid" : 13, 
    "eng" : "You will be aware from the press and television that there have been a 
             number of bomb explosions and killings." 
}
```

Comment: btw, `barbar black sheep, have you any foo` would be `barbar schwarzes Schaf, hast du etwas foo` in German.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use [`find_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) to find the doc with the maximum `uid` by sorting on that field descending:

```py
db.things.find_one(sort=[("uid", -1)])
```

or using the defined constant:

```
db.things.find_one(sort=[("uid", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

Comment: isn't it more expensive to do `find()` or `find_one()` without the reduced map, especially when i have close to 2,000,000 documents in the database.

Comment: No, but you'd still want to make sure you had an index on `uid` if you need this to be performant.

Comment: Yo may use more descriptive predifined constants to point direction argument: `pymongo.DESCENDING` instead of `-1` and `pymongo.ASCENDING` instead of `1`